# Amcharts addInitHandler not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, amcharts, column-chart

I am trying to replicate the use case of putting an empty bar where there is no data in a column chart as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639120/handle-empty-bars-in-column-chart-in-amcharts) in Angular 2.

But it throws the following error -

[image]

How shall I make addInitHandler work in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure since I have not used Amcharts, but looking at the documents at their github page I think you might need to use `addListener` instead of `addinithandler`

```
this.AmCharts.addListener(this.chart, "init", (e) => {
  // Do stuff when the event happens
});
```

See [enter link description here](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2)